# How to vectorise a lookup using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to vectorise an operation that returns `True` if  a cell value is not within a list using a lookup dictionary. What I'm looking to achieve will become clearer with this reproducible example.

First I have created a dictionary where keys reflect cell values of the column `source` in the dataframe `df` built below.

`SectorOverlaps ={'21438-26838': ['110-1058', '114-1058', '120-1058', '124-1058', '130-1058', '134-1058', '21438-36838', '15915-21420', '21438-16838', '25915-21420', '21438-26838', '35915-21420', '21438-36838', '21438-16838', '21438-26838', '9112-10029'], '110-1650': ['110-1650', '120-1650', '130-1650', '21438-12663', '21438-12663', '21438-12363', '19015-21420', '21438-22663', '21438-22663', '21438-22363', '29015-21420', '21438-32663', '21438-32663', '21438-32363', '39015-21420']}`

`df = pd.read_json('{"source":{"0":"110-1650","1":"21438-26838"},"dest":{"0":"120-468","1":"114-7616"}}')`

I apply a lookup that returns `True` when the cell value for the `dest` column is not within list contained in the lookup dictionary, `SectorOverlaps`

`df.apply(lambda x: x['dest'] not in SectorOverlaps[x['source']], axis=1)`

This result is fine, and it works, but it's really slow and I have to apply this operation over millions of rows.

Does anybody have any advice as to how to speed this up or, at best, vectorise this operation?

Comment: A simple speed up would be to use a set instead of a list in the `SectorOverlaps` dictionary. Membership testing is way faster using a set, but the gain may be negligible depending on the size of the list.

Comment: _it works, but it’s really slow_ How slow is “really slow”?